# First Order Differential Equations - length of the arc joining two points on it

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What curve lying above the x axis has the property that the length of the arc joining any two points on it is proportional to the area under that arc?

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: This may help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21380/proving-that-there-exists-a-unique-fx-given-area-and-arc-length-of-fx-on-a-g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y=f(x)$ and $(x_{1}, y_{1})$ and $(x_{2}, y_{2})$ are the two points on the curve such that $y_{2} > y_{1}$ and $x_{2} > x_{1}$ then
\begin{eqnarray}
s &=& \int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}} \sqrt{ 1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 } dx \\
  &\propto& \int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}}f(x)dx
\end{eqnarray}
EDIT: Further information.

Thus we can say (wlog)
\begin{equation}
ky=\sqrt{1+y'^{2}}
\end{equation}
Where $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$. Thus
\begin{eqnarray}
ky           &=& \sqrt{1+y'^{2}} \\
\iff y'^{2} &=& k^{2}y^{2}-1 \\
\iff y'       &=& \sqrt{k^{2}y^{2}-1}
\end{eqnarray}
Re-arranging
\begin{equation}
\int dx = \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{k^{2}y^{2}-1}}
\end{equation}
redefining $\hat{y}=ky, \implies d \hat{y}  =kdy$
So
\begin{eqnarray}
x+c &=& \frac{1}{k}\int \frac{d\hat{y}}{\sqrt{\hat{y}^{2}-1}} \\
    &=& \frac{1}{k}\cosh^{-1} \hat{y} + C \\
\end{eqnarray}
Thus
\begin{equation}
y=\alpha + k\cosh(kx+\hat{C})
\end{equation}
Where $\alpha = -C$ and $\hat{C}=kc$.

Comment: I don't understand, so what curve has this property?

Comment: $y = C$, where $C$ is a constant perhaps?

Comment: I'll add a further comment. See edit.